# Encode, Decode and save to sql

Tags: php, sql, encoding, base64

I have been learning how to encode and decode and save the data, but there is something that I can't get around and I need your help.

So please let me explain the flow...

User gets in to the site, submit a form and waits...
so what happen whe he/she waits?
result.php do all the magic.

```
    <?php 
        include ('conectiontodb.php');

if (!isset($_POST['data']) {
$datas = htmlentities($_POST['data'], ENT_NOQUOTES);

$decode= base64_decode('$datas');
parse_str($decode, $params);

$name = htmlentities($params['names'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
$midname = htmlentities($params['midname'], ENT_NOQUOTES);

echo $name . ' ' . $midname;

/*   Output
 * Lúferis Mondoña Ardérs
*/

$query = "INSERT INTO names (name, midnames)
          VALUES ($name, $midname)";  
          $dbconection->query($query);
header (location : thankyou.php);
} else {
echo 'Data missing';
}
    ?>
```

So this is a very basic code, part of what I use, I know that I'm not using a valid sanitation before I save the data but that is not the point, the thing is that the data is not get saved properly what I mean by that is:
Table

```
 names    | midnames
--------------------------------- 
 LÃ®feris | Mondo a ArdÃ®&copy;rs
```

If I echo the data from the SQL it will show as it is been saved in the data base, there is not replace for the data like when you use a json and the symbols get display properly 

the data is display with a header

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

the SQL uses utf8_unicode_ci, and the columns uses varchart() ... now here is the catch, I use the base64 code to encode a long url with data because I use GET instead of POST because the data goes to an api which return a data in the URL so that is why I use get to the result from the api...

result.php?data=TMO6ZmVyaXMgTW9uZG/DsWEgQXJkw6lycw==&res=pass&nc=99999
so once I get the result from the api I decode the 64 and saved the data, but the like I said if I echo the data it display fine, but after I saved it and then echo it or with a json from the SQL it doesn't display properly.... so what is wrong with the base64? ...

If I save the data before it goes to the API everything is fine, but I need to send the data to the api and saved the returned data...

So, Questions...

How do I proper encode the data so the í, ó, ú, ñ... doesn't get mess up?... 
here is the weird part the data doesn't get mess up when it goes out or when it return, the data gets mess up when it gets encode...
at this point I don't really care whether the data is encode or not, the thing is
in the input text you can clearly see " í " and let say you hit submit using GET in the url you'll see:
**file.php?name=ç¥**
and not the actual " í " so why is that?... please I really need some help on this...

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: It says base74-encode in the code....?

Comment: yes, my bad, it shouold be base64, thank you.

Comment: The data seems to be saved in utf-8 format... How do you display it when it shows up in the wrong way? From command prompt connected to tje sql server or on a php/html page? Maybe you need to set the encoding of the prompt to utf-8 or the webpage to utf-8 because it looks like a utf-8 representation that gets displayed using the wrong display encoding...

Comment: To display the data I use echo(); and json() or print_r()... the problem is when the data is saved, the data that is save in the sql came from a base64 after the data has gone through the api, but the API don't change the data only reads it... so, before the data is enconde in 64base it is display using echo() and the information is display correctly let say... echo $name; then $data='name='.$name; $datas = base64_encode($data); and that is it...